# Impact of gradle.properties as input to task?

Tags: java, caching, gradle

I'm looking at a legacy Gradle file that has something like the following:

`inputs.file rootProject.file( "gradle.properties" )`

Gradle was recently updated from 1.12 or so to 4.3. I'm assuming that this line was introduced to ensure the build cache is invalidated for this particular task. As written (for version 4.3) does this input declaration do anything?

At a higher level, what's the relationship between `gradle.properties` and cache invalidation?